# Flex Mobile Web Application - Native Camera and GPS Access

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, web

I have an old flex web application which now needs to access the camera and gps on a smartphone.
I see there are external libraries to do some of the work for you but what need is native flex support for accessing the phone's GPS and camera from the mobile browser.

The application can be recompiled to any version of flex from 3 to 4.6 if necessary.

To clarify further: The SWF file is embedded in a web page which is then displayed on a tablet/phone (android, ios, etc). I want to be able to read the current GPS coordinates from the hardware GPS and be able to take a picture with the onboard camera.

If this is 100% impossible, I can call a JavaScript function to read the photo and GPS from a third party component, this component would need to be all encompassing as far as mobile devices are and be compatible with the flex externalinterface setup.

Thanks for you help in advance.
Pete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pretty much forget about using flash on mobile and desktop for that matter, its a dead end technology now.

Sadly there are very very few mobile devices that will give you browser access to the camera yet. There are a few, but iOS for example has not yet implemented the standard. So you are not going to be able to readily access the camera for at least another year or so. It depends on when Apple, Google and Microsoft get their act together.

As for GPS all the mobile browsers that anyone uses supports the geolocation specification so you can know where the user is.

http://professionalaspnet.com/archive/2012/05/25/A-Study-Using-The-HTML5-Geolocation-API.aspx